# Power BI DAX - How to use switch function to display both selected values

Tags: powerbi, reporting, dax

I have a report where I am comparing different Register sales.

It works completely fine when I select ONE Register to display - but when I select a second Register it displays no data.

It would be amazing if I could somehow select muliple Registers and display them the same as it displays one register

I am currently using the switch function to achieve this.

here is my DAX.

> Lets me switch between selected consoles

```
SPoS = if(HASONEVALUE('sp'[Select PoS]),VALUES('sp'[Select PoS]),BLANK())
```

> Displays the results of the selected Console

```
SP_PoS = SWITCH( [SPoS], "DriveThru PoS",dt[SP_drivethrupos], "Main PoS",dt[SP_mainpos], "Backup PoS",dt[SP_secondpos], "Cafe PoS",dt[SP_cafepos])
```

> enables selected console to dynamically change measure

```
SP_cafepos = IF(HASONEVALUE(dm[Select a Measure]),SWITCH(VALUES(dm[Select a Measure]),"SalesInc",[sp_sales],"Quantity",[sp_qty],"Gross Profit",[rp_gp]))
SP_drivethrupos = IF(HASONEVALUE(dm[Select a Measure]),SWITCH(VALUES(dm[Select a Measure]),"SalesInc",[sp_sales],"Quantity",[sp_qty],"Gross Profit",[rp_gp]))
SP_mainpos = IF(HASONEVALUE(dm[Select a Measure]),SWITCH(VALUES(dm[Select a Measure]),"SalesInc",[sp_sales],"Quantity",[sp_qty],"Gross Profit",[rp_gp]))
SP_secondpos = IF(HASONEVALUE(dm[Select a Measure]),SWITCH(VALUES(dm[Select a Measure]),"SalesInc",[sp_sales],"Quantity",[sp_qty],"Gross Profit",[rp_gp]))
```

> Enables me to change the Measure I want to display

```
SelectedMeasure = IF(HASONEVALUE(dm[Select a Measure]),SWITCH(VALUES(dm[Select a Measure]),"SalesInc",SUM(dt[SalesInc]),"Quantity",SUM(dt[Quantity]),"Gross Profit",SUM(dt[GP])))
```

> I use these measures to filter to the correct Register

```
sp_qty = CALCULATE (SUM ( dt[Quantity]),FILTER ( dt, dt[RegisterID] IN VALUES ( 'sp'[RegisterID]) ))
sp_sales = CALCULATE (SUM ( dt[SalesInc]),FILTER ( dt, dt[RegisterID] IN VALUES ( 'sp'[RegisterID]) ))
sp_gp = CALCULATE (SUM ( dt[gp]),FILTER ( dt, dt[RegisterID] IN VALUES ( 'sp'[RegisterID]) ))
```

> Some Pictures Below for Clarity

[image: One Register Selected Works Perfectly]

[image: 2nd Register Selected Displays Nothing]

> Pic 1: One Register Selected Works Perfectly
>
> Pic 2: 2nd Register Selected Displays Nothing
>
> Pic 3: Data Structure

[image: Data Structure]